# How could a thread return to a place different from the one it come from in C#?

Tags: c#, return, callstack

How could a thread return to a place different from the one it come from in C#?

I met the following excerpt in the **CLR via C#** book:

> Whenever you obtain a stack trace, you might find that some methods in the actual call stack don’t
>   appear in the stack trace string. There are two reasons for this. **First, the stack is really a record of where the thread should return to, not where the thread has come from.** Second, the just-in-time (JIT) compiler can inline methods to avoid the overhead of calling and returning from a separate method.

Does the excerpt mean that a thread can return not to the place where it come from or does it mean something else? In the former case, could someone give an example when a thread does not return to where it come from, please? And in the latter case, could someone explain what it means in a foolproof manner, please?

For me the excerpt is confusing, because I am used to the behavior of the `return` statements in functions - they always return to the caller - the place where the thread come from and I can not imagine a case when they would return to a different place. Does it have to do anything with the `async/await` syntactic sugar?

Comment: A thread never "returns" anything to anywhere. It just ends and disappears if nobody is storing a reference to it. Like if you shoot a bullet with a gun. It's Fire&Forget. Or like you  close an Application. It's just gone.

Comment: @Holger, could you explain then what is meant by the thread being returned in the **CLR via C#** book, please?

Comment: For this, we wood need some code. We cannot interpret the words of an unknown book. Probbably when you start a thread, you get a reference to the thread. That's like, if you see a plane leaving, you get the flight number in return. But it cannot be read as "the plane is returning something to you". It's still in the air and flying.

Comment: @Holger, it is not always the case that we are granted with such a luxury as a practical example. Sometimes there is only theory presented to us. :)

Comment: If you have `main` calling `f1` calling `f2` which calls `f3` and an exception is thrown in `f3`, then you would expect to see f3, f2, f1 and main in the stack trace associated with the exception.  However, the JITter may decide that f2 is simple enough that it gets *inlined* away in a release build.  In that case, if you were to look at the stack trace, there'd be no `f2` listed in the stack.  Though this might be an interesting question, you don't really need to worry about it.

Comment: @Flydog57, thank you for your time and attention. But am not asking about the inline case in my question.

Comment: The jitter can do whatever it wants, as long as the program behaves in the way that the programmer has decided.  Back when I was doing embedded systems on an 8 bit computer, we'd occasionally play stack games (in certain cases, pop off the return address from the stack and push another one instead).  Unless you have an example of a production stack (it's very unlikely that you will see this in a debug build) that illustrates what you are seeing, you probably won't get an answer.  An, oh, by the way, async programming *can* produce stacks that make little sense unless you did very deep into it

Comment: @Flydog57, ok. Thank you. (:

Comment: @qqqqqqq It's the requirement of this site, that you present code. It's not a tutorial site. As a beginner you dig much too deep. You don't need to understand the inner details of the CLR. You need that if you try to write your own new language. Threads are kind of outdated (or encapsulated with more sophisticated technology). Go ahead with questions about async/await. That's the entry point for todays C# programmers. Understand concepts, not the byte-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The excerpt is making a point about the purpose of the return address being pushed on the stack: it's really the address to return, not the address of the jump's origin.

Another way to look at it is that calling wouldn't need to pair up with returning: instead of `call-return` you could use `push-jump-return`, which would put you to a location you pushed, not to the location from which you jumped.

Comment: It really would be nice to see how such a case - `push-jump-return` can be reproduced in C#. :)

Comment: Side note: whether you can make such function in C# (which seem to be implied in question) is very different question, but since stack trace (which is what question refers to) shows all calls from possible sources including native method it indeed possible (at least theoretically) see methods that return to place different than origin of the call.

Answer (score 1):

Let us think of this scenario:

Thread A starts Thread B.

Thread B starts and contunies it's work in Thread C.

Now it "returned" to Thread C, despite comming from Thread A.

Comment: Call stack will not really show that... And thread can't really "continue to work on other thread" - not exactly clear what you mean here... (Managed threads can migrate between physical threads... that?)

Comment: Yeah, your example makes little sense in the context of a question about a stack trace (or, in general)

Comment: @Flydog57 Do you need an explanation on why this explains "First, the stack is really a record of where the thread should return to, not where the thread has come from." ?

Comment: Each thread has it's own stack.  Threads don't "return" to anything.  They run until they stop running and then they're stopped (and they either end or are returned to the thread pool).  Each thread does it's own "work" (in fact, when I explain threads to folks, I usually say something like "this work it dispatched to another thread from the pool").  You may put some synchronization mechanism in so that when one thread completes another thread may continue.  But, you won't easily see that in a stack trace